# Use MeteorJS with PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, meteor, npm

I would like to know what is the best way at the moment to use PostgreSQL instead of MongoDb with MeteorJS.

I'm using meteor 1.8 and I found the package https://github.com/numtel/meteor-pg but to make it work i need this package : https://github.com/numtel/meteor-pg-server but when i install it i have this error :

meteor add numtel:pg-server
 => Errors while adding packages:

While checking for numtel:pg-server@1.0.1:
error: No compatible binary build found for this package. Contact the package author and ask them to publish it
for your platform.

I think it's not compatible with meteorJS 1.8 ...

So i found another package : https://github.com/Richie765/meteor-pg

And the problem with this one is when I install it, I have this error :

meteor npm install meteor-pg --save

added 26 packages from 47 contributors and audited 1904 packages in 5.961s
found 2 vulnerabilities (1 low, 1 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

meteor npm audit fix
up to date in 2.264s
fixed 0 of 2 vulnerabilities in 1904 scanned packages
  2 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated

meteor npm audit

```
                   === npm audit security report ===


                             Manual Review
         Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve

      Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance
```

High            Cross-Site Scripting

Package         bootstrap-tagsinput

Patched in      No patch available

Dependency of   bootstrap-tagsinput

Path            bootstrap-tagsinput

More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/124

Low             Prototype Pollution

Package         lodash

Patched in      >=4.17.5

Dependency of   modernizr

Path            modernizr > lodash

More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/577

I think this problem came because I'm using an Admin template which is : Angle - Bootstrap Admin Template (http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB04HF123) because when i restart my project, there is the following error :

Unable to resolve some modules:

"jquery.flot.spline/jquery.flot.spline.js" in /C/Users/R-D/Desktop/meteor/imports/startup/client/vendor.js
(web.browser.legacy)
  "jqueryui-touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js" in
/C/Users/R-D/Desktop/meteor/imports/startup/client/vendor.js (web.browser.legacy)

If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider running:

meteor npm install --save jquery.flot.spline jqueryui-touch-punch

so i execute meteor npm install --save jquery.flot.spline jqueryui-touch-punch then :

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: jquery.flot.spline@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\R-D\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-11-26T10_35_09_102Z-debug.log

I'm sorry if my problem is dumb, i'm a young developper and it's the first framework i'm using.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

you can you use it with any database you want but you will lost the real meteor fell like real time data and other cool feature meteor have 
you can use https://node-postgres.com/ for the installation and use Meteor.wrapAsync() for the operation